# Convert eGrep to Grep

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

I have a query using eGrep in Bash on MacOS, and wondered how to convert it to grep query instead, as I understand eGrep is deprecated now, or is being replaced in favour of grep?

I need to convert this;

```
egrep "^\s+2\.\d+\.\d+$" <(rbenv install -l) | tail -1
```

Basically it is looking in the RBENV install list for the latest 2.x version so it can install it later on, this portion of code harvests the version number I need and stores it in a VAR for later use ;)
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Carcigenicate grep -E and egrep is the same. They mean extended grep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out the final query is this

```
latest_2x_ruby=$(grep -E "^2\.\d+\.\d+$" <(rbenv install -l) | tail -1)
```

This will retrieve all version numbers starting with 2 and pick the last one from the list. this way I Can just change the number at the start to retrieve the latest version of a specific major version.

However, if I want to run this from a BASH script I had to do it this way;

```
latest_2x_ruby="$( rbenv install -l | grep -E '^2\.\d+\.\d+$' | tail -1 )"
```

Comment: Using backticks \` is discouraged. Use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: While this may be a valid workaround for your specific case, it isn't a very useful answer to the question.

Comment: I agree, and welcome improvements to this, as the current suggestions aren't working for me :/

Comment: If you edit your question to provide us with a sample output of the `rbenv` command then it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: It doesn't output anything, that's the problem :/

Comment: I mean just `rbenv install -l`, not the full pipe. By the way I just looked on [rbenv GitHub](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and `rbenv install` isn't mentioned as a command - maybe you should be using `versions`?

Comment: It's in point 5 of the how to setup rBenv section ;)

So `rbenv install -l` outputs this;

1.8.5-p52
1.8.5-p113
1.8.5-p114
1.8.5-p115
1.8.5-p231
1.8.6
1.8.6-p36
1.8.6-p110
1.8.6-p111
1.8.6-p114
1.8.6-p230
1.8.6-p286
1.8.6-p287
1.8.6-p368
1.8.6-p369
1.8.6-p383
1.8.6-p388
1.8.6-p398
1.8.6-p399
1.8.6-p420
1.8.7-preview1
1.8.7-preview2
1.8.7-preview3
1.8.7-preview4
1.8.7
1.8.7-p17
1.8.7-p22
1.8.7-p71
1.8.7-p72
1.8.7-p160
1.8.7-p173
1.8.7-p174
...

There's more but I can't fit it in the reply. It is basically a list of every ruby version available

Answer (score 3):

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

`egrep` is a synonym for grep -E

`fgrep` is a synonym for grep -F

In your case
`egrep "^\s+2\.\d+\.\d+$" <(rbenv install -l) | tail -1`

simply becomes

`grep -E "^\s+2\.\d+\.\d+$" <(rbenv install -l) | tail -1`

Comment: Except now my query isn't working at all, even in it's original state, can anyone see what's wrong with it

Comment: This is the full code `latest_2x_ruby=\`egrep "^\s+2\.\d+\.\d+$" <(rbenv install -l) | tail -1\``. However the VAR isn't being populated anymore, but `rbenv install -l` works when it's run on it's own. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, [`egrep` is an obsolescent version equivalent to `grep -E`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/egrep.html).

The reason that your original command doesn't work on a non-GNU version of grep is because you are using unsupported syntax like `\s` and `\d`. This is a separate feature to Extended Regular Expression support (which is what you get with `-E`).

Try changing `\s` and `\d` for their equivalent longhand syntax:

```
grep -E '^[[:space:]]+2\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$' <(rbenv install -l) | tail -1
```

As an aside, I would always recommend using single quotes around any string literal, to avoid characters such as `$` and `\` from potentially being interpreted by the shell.

For maximum compatibility you may also want to consider using a pipe rather than a process substitution, and only using Basic Regular Expression syntax (i.e. replacing `+` with `\{1,\}`):

```
version=$(rbenv install -l | 
  grep '^[[:space:]]\{1,\}2\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}$' |
  tail -1)
```

Comment: grep without `-E` can't handle `+` but you can do `grep '^[[:space:]][[:space:]]*2\.[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*$'` instead. GNU grep's BRE can handle most (all?) of ERE with extra backslashes, but POSIX does not specify that.

Comment: @Adam according to [Open Group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06) it looks like interval expressions `\{m,n\}` are supported as part of BREs.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I believe I've encountered BRE implementations that can't handle that but perhaps I'm mistaken (or they're too obscure to matter). I don't know which `grep` comes with OS X and can't verify its compliance to this. (Also, here's an [updated link for POSIX BREs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06).)